# Build project - Nuget Error

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

The error occurs only on one machine.

## Attempts

### Wrong paths

I thought the path of any source may be wrong, so I opened the `NuGet.Config` to check and the 3 paths are correct and there!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="Nightly ASP.NET Web Stack" value="http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/" />
    <add key="Bind Solution" value="W:\Cloud\Dropbox\Bind Defaults\Nuget Repository" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

### Nuget.exe not exist

Checked on `.nuget` folder and .exe is in the directory!
Checked in Path of windows and there is!

I tried to run the command manually and it run successfully!

`nuget install packages.config -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "W:\C
lients\creditoimobiliariobb\sistema\src\CreditoImobiliarioBB\ "`

## Full error:

> Error 1   The system cannot find the path specified.  CreditoImobiliarioBB.Domain
>
> Error 2   The command ""W:\Clients\creditoimobiliariobb\sistema\src\CreditoImobiliarioBB.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "W:\Clients\creditoimobiliariobb\sistema\src\CreditoImobiliarioBB\CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "W:\Clients\creditoimobiliariobb\sistema\src\CreditoImobiliarioBB\ " " exited with code -1. CreditoImobiliarioBB.Domain

## Considerations

Only projects that have local packages (Source is `key="Bind Solution" value="W:\Cloud\Dropbox\Bind Defaults\Nuget Repository"`) is that they are in trouble. And recently the location of packages moved to another directory (in this case to `W:\Cloud\Dropbox\Bind Defaults\Nuget Repository`).

Comment: probably not but have you noticed the space? - > **"W:\C** **lients\cr"**

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem recently, I fixed it by doing this:

1. Update Visual Studio to the latest version. (Extensions and Updates - Product Updates)
2. Update Nugget to the latest version. (Extensions and Updates - Visual Studio Gallery)
3. Clear the Package Cache. (Options - Package Manager)
4. Rebuild the solution.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with NuGet.exe and WG.exe for WebGrease. I realized that with my Virus Protection turned on, it wasn't allowing the .exe files to come down properly. Once I disabled my Virus Protection, I was able to get everything I need (company is using McAfee).